# Changing color of labels one after another

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a window with some labels. I want the BackColor of the labels to change depending of some tests I am running:

```
private void btnStartTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(Tests.FirstTest())
        {
            this.lblFirstTest.BackColor = Color.LawnGreen;
        }
        else
        {
            this.lblFirstTest.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }

        if(Tests.SecondTest())
        {
            this.lblSecondTest.BackColor = Color.LawnGreen;
        }
        else
        {
            this.lblSecondTest.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }

        //and so on...
    }
```

I want the labels to change color one after another to show progress.
But right now the color change only takes effect at the end of the method. So all labels change color at the same time.

Why is this? And what can I change to get the desired effect?

Comment: Your UI thread will hang if you have long running process on it, such as your tests. So your code gives no chance to draw the updates..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perform a [`Refresh`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh(v=vs.110).aspx) on the form after each colour change. That should force visual elements to be updated and redrawn, giving the desired effect. This is the simplest way that does not involve threading.

Answer (score 0):

Like BugFinder said... Run the method on a different thread (Task.RunAsync(()=> {})) ... But in that case you have to use a dispatcher to be able to assign values to the controls (or else Exception)